# Loop and echo specified JSON content

Tags: php, arrays, json

How can I show **artistName** only in **"wrapperType":"track"**?

Here's the JSON example:

```
{  
   "resultCount":5,
   "results":[  
      {  
         "wrapperType":"collection",
         "artistName":"Liam Payne"
      },
      {  
         "wrapperType":"track",
         "artistName":"Liam Payne & French Montana"
      }
      {  
         "wrapperType":"track",
         "artistName":"Liam Payne & French Montana"
      }
      {  
         "wrapperType":"track",
         "artistName":"French Montana"
      }
      {  
         "wrapperType":"track",
         "artistName":"French Montana"
      }
   ]
}
```

and the php code:

but this will display all values

```
foreach ($obj->results as $row){
    echo $row->artistName;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put `if($row->wrapperType == "track")` condition in your code.

Try below code:

```
foreach ($obj->results as $row){
    if($row->wrapperType == "track"){
        echo $row->artistName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a condition in the foreach loop to check if wrapperType is track

Like:

```
foreach ($obj->results as $row){
    if($row->wrapperType == "track"){
      echo $row->artistName;
   }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering this question! An answer that contains only code is not very helpful without some additional detail. For example, _why_ doe  your answer work? Why not do it a different way? Including these things in your answers helps the question-asker - and others - to better understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($obj->results as $row){
    echo $row->artistName;
}
```

loops through all available items. You should check `wrapperType`:

```
foreach ($obj->results as $row){
  if ($row->wrapperType == 'track') {
    echo $row->artistName;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first your json is not valid (missing `,`) , you can check your desired output [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/559b3db2fcd6b0bdb1dbd7b2ba475c3f09d648e6)

in loop used `$data['results']` instead of `$obj->results`

Used if condition like `if($row['wrapperType']=='track'){// if condition for what type of data you want`

```
$data='{
    "resultCount": 5,
    "results": [{
            "wrapperType": "collection",
            "artistName": "Liam Payne"
        },
        {
            "wrapperType": "track",
            "artistName": "Liam Payne & French Montana"
        }, {
            "wrapperType": "track",
            "artistName": "Liam Payne & French Montana"
        }, {
            "wrapperType": "track",
            "artistName": "French Montana"
        }, {
            "wrapperType": "track",
            "artistName": "French Montana"
        }
    ]
}';
$data=json_decode($data, true);
print_r($data['results']);
foreach ($data['results'] as $row){
    if($row['wrapperType']=='track'){// if condition for what type of data you want
       echo "Artist Name: ".$row['artistName'];
       echo "Wrapper Type: ".$row['wrapperType'];
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the difference between `$data['results']` and `$obj->results`?